# Restrict User To Specific Entities In CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-4

I am new to CRM Environment. I have Guest Login and user role for my client. I have a lot of custom entities in my Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 online. I want to give access to my client to some specific entities so he can play with it ,  without messing with my other entities.

I want that when my client logs in he can only view one custom entity in the site map. Nothing else ! 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the security roles in order to customize the security access to different entities. First set up the Security role.

1. Go to Settings -> Security -> Security Role and create a new role and give it any name.

Now click on the security role that you created and select the roles that you want to assign. Since you want to assign roles to some specific entities you can select the Read, Write, Edit and other available roles against those entities and remove all the roles against other entities.

After this you can assign users to this new role you have created.

Note: This way you can only hide the entities and not the main grid e.g Sales, Workplace, Marketing etc. tabs will show on you ribbon but the entities underneath it can be hidden through the above procedure.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the security roles of the user in order to access only the entities (standard and custom) you chose.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334717.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To show or hide a sub area in `SiteMap` based on access control security roles, one can easily do this using the Privilege tag in the `SiteMap` as follows:

```
<SubArea Id=”crm_myentity” Entity=”crm_myentity”>
<Privilege Entity=”crm_myentity” Privilege=”Read” />
</SubArea>
```

Based on the above, this `SubArea` will only be shown to users who have security roles with read privilege of the custom entity: `crm_myentity`.

You can add the privilege tag above to any `SubArea` and the entity in the privilege tag can be any entity and doesn’t have to be the same one as the sub area. For example, the following is also applicable:

```
<SubArea Id=”contact” Entity=”contact” Title=”Contacts”>
<Privilege Entity=”crm_myentity” Privilege=”Read” />
</SubArea>
```

This will hide the contact `SubArea` for users without the read privilege for the entity `crm_myentity`. You can mix and match as much as you want to show and hide any `SubArea` in the `SiteMap` based on any entity you require whether they are customisable. System or custom entities.